# Oracle foreign data wrapper

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, oracle-fdw

I have master-slave architecture. On the slave I have an Oracle database with two schemas, e.g. `TEST1` and `TEST2`.

I have all objects (e.g. `EMPLOYEES`) stored in schema `TEST1`, and user `TEST1` (or admin) has given read only privileges on `TEST1.EMPLOYEES` to `TEST2`, so when I use `TEST1.EMPLOYEES` in a query on the Oracle database I can access its data.

How can I implement the same using Oracle foreign data wrapper in postgres 9.5 because I have credentials for `TEST2` and not `TEST1`?
When I try to access the foreign table it give an error saying that `TEST2.EMPLOYEES` does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that if you define the user mapping with the credentials of user `TEST2` and the foreign table with the `schema` option, i.e.

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE ... OPTIONS (schema 'TEST1', table 'EMPLOYEES');
```

Comment: Your answer helped me...  My issue resolved.. Thx a lot

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : in postgres-9.4, these options were named `schema_name` and `table_name` (I don't know if these *keywords* have been renamed inlater versions)

Comment: @wildplasser: You are mistaken. The names of the options are not ordained by PostgreSQL, they are defined by the foreign data wrapper. The main reason why names in oracle_fdw and postgres_fdw differ is that I wrote oracle_fdw first, so I couldn't copy behaviour...